# Can I use twitter bootstrap plugin on top of my working grails app?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails, twitter

- Currently the application is using jquery-UI theme and mostly custom css. Do I need to redesign from the scratch !? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can. But it's not a *drop-in replacement*, requires a lot of rework

Comment: Agree with @IgorArtamonov. If you were starting with a clean project, it's great to install-templates and modify the scaffolding to use Bootstrap.

Comment: Another agreeance with @IgorArtamonov, we've done this for a project in the past, and while it will work, bootstrap uses certain html components with specific classes set for its scaffolding. If you simply want some of the javascript features it is quite a quick win however.